# What determines the energy spacing of individual orbitals within an energy band in a material?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, pauli-exclusion-principle

Within a material, electrons exist within energy bands, often referred to as the "conduction" band and the "valence" band (and I imagine there can be other named bands as well). I understand why this occurs -- that electrons exist in orbitals around an atom and that when you bring many atoms together in a material, these orbitals aren't allowed to overlap due to the Pauli Exclusion principle and therefore form large bands of nearly continuous energy states. My question however is that these states within a band are *not* actually continuous but instead differ by very small energy levels, so what determines the value of these very small energy gaps within the band? For instance, the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure) on the subject says:

> Since the number of atoms in a macroscopic piece of solid is a very large number (N~$10^{22}$) the number of orbitals is very large and thus they are very closely spaced in energy (of the order of $10^{−22}$ eV)

however this does not seem very well motivated to me at all. Am I to understand the energy spacing is simply proportional to the inverse of the number of atoms in a material? If I continue to add more atoms to the material, would I expect that the energy levels just get more and more closely packed, or is there something else determining this energy spacing?

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here (although it's not quite relevant to your actual question).  Pauli exclusion is *not* the reason why band structure exists. Energy bands can actually be solved for by solving the *single-particle* Schrodinger equation. Pauli exclusion comes in when you start *populating* the states in these bands with electrons. Since the electrons can't occupy the same state, you have to put them in different states, which process fills up the bands to a certain level.

Comment: (However: electron-electron interactions (including exchange interactions due to Pauli principle) do change the band structure: you can likely do some kind of Hartree-Fock calculation to get better approximations of the bands. Nonetheless, the very *existence* of bands themselves is still a single-particle notion.)